# Why omitting the await keyword results in different behavior?

Tags: dart, mockito

I am testing some middleware code. When the function `middleware.call` is provoked I get different results depending on whether I use the keyword `await` when calling it.

This is testing code:

```
final actionLog = <dynamic>[];
final Function(dynamic) next = (dynamic action){
  actionLog.add(action);
};

test('Fetching a dictionary entry successfully', () async {
  DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry = new DictionaryEntry(2333, 'after', null, null);
  when(
      mockApi
          .getDictionaryEntry('after', any, any)
  ).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(dictionaryEntry));

  final action = FetchDictionaryEntryAction('after');
  await dictionaryMiddleware.call(mocksStore, action, next);

// length of action log is 2 
// when I don't use await before calling  dictionaryMiddleware.call
// but its 4 when using await before calling the function.

  print("length of action log " + actionLog.length.toString());
  print(actionLog);
});
```

This is the middleware:

```
@override
Future<void> call(
    Store<AppState> store, dynamic action, NextDispatcher next) async {

  next(action);

  if(action is FetchDictionaryEntryAction){
    await _fetchDictionaryEntry(action.speechText,
        action.fromLanguage, action.toLanguage, next
    );
  }

}


Future<void> _fetchDictionaryEntry(
  String speechText, 
  String fromLanguage,
  String toLanguage,
  NextDispatcher next
) async {

  if(speechText == null || speechText?.length == 0){
    next(ReceivedDictionaryEntryAction(dictionaryEntry: null));
    return;
  }

  next(RequestingDictionaryEntryAction());

  try{
    final DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry =
      await this.api.getDictionaryEntry(speechText, fromLanguage, toLanguage);
    next(ReceivedDictionaryEntryAction(dictionaryEntry: dictionaryEntry));
    next(CacheDictionaryEntryAction(dictionaryEntry));

  }catch(e){
    next(ErrorLoadingDictionaryEntryAction);
  }

}
```

I am wondering why does `next()` (the dispatcher in the middleware) get called only 2 times when not using `await` as apposed to getting called 4 times when using `await` which is the normal behavior.

Comment: Without `await`ing `dictionaryMiddleware.call(...)`, your test finishes before `this.api.getDictionaryEntry` ever gets a chance to finish and call `next()` the last two times.

Comment: And if your follow-up question is "But I mocked `getDictionaryEntry`, so why doesn't it complete immediately?", then it's because `await` *always* yields execution.

Comment: So the code executes and then when it reaches `await this.api.getDictionaryEntry` the execution gets delayed. However, meanwhile the test continues and finishes and that's why it appears that `next()` only gets called twice? (length of `actionLog` is 2)